# showing the marker in Google Maps using Intent --> Uri.parse(geo: ...)

Tags: android, google-maps, android-intent

i don't wanna use a MapView an some Overlays. I only want to use the given intent Google Maps. Showing a Adress in Google Maps works fine when i call it from my application using Uri.parse("geo: ...") ... But i only see the map centered at the given adress. There are no marker or "bubble" like they are when i do a search in google maps. I can define the Zoom in the Uri with "z=12" ... Is there one thing i had to set up to see the marker and the "bubble"?!

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there one thing i had to set up to see the marker and the "bubble"?!

There is no documented and supported means to put a "marker" or "bubble" when you use a `geo:` URL. Bear in mind that it might not be Google Maps that winds up responding to that URL -- the user could have installed another mapping application that they choose to handle such requests.

Comment: Ah yes thats right...instead of that can i use "http://maps.google.com/maps" in the uri?..Maybe is there an alternative?

Comment: @user683813: If there's a way of constructing a `maps.google.com/maps` URL that causes the Web-based maps to display a marker, that's certainly worth trying. I have no idea if it will work, though, as I have not tried it personally.

Comment: Okay...Testing a little bit i found a Solution that works fine:

using 

Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?q=" + STREET + "+" + NUMBER + "&" + CITY);

it will open the Google Maps App showing the Adress with Marker and "Bubble".

Hope this will also help another one.